# anchor to cover img on hover

Tags: html, css

I have the code:

```
<a class="preview" href="">
    <img class="frame" src="tmp5.png" alt="" />
</a>

a.preview:hover {
    background:red url('../images/icons/preview.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:40;
}
a.preview:hover img {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Image is also styled by CSS, I just want to add an anchor background on hover that will cover the image.

I'd like to avoid usage of JS if possible.

Anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: Do you need this to work in IE7?

Comment: Would be awesome as I'd like to support this browser.

Answer (score 1):

howabout:

```
a.preview:hover img {
    visibility:hidden
}
```

Comment: This would work if I'd like to hide the image. I just want to add small icon (preview) to the anchor :)

Comment: Ah, then you could position an element over the image, hide it normally, and show it on hover.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is trying not to cover the image with an anchor but adding a (second?) image INSIDE the anchor that will become visible when hovering the anchor. Your HTML would look something like this:

```
<a class="preview" href="">
    <img class="hover" src="/images/icons/preview.png" alt="" />
    <img class="frame" src="tmp5.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

However, to position this image near or over the anchor we'll have to make the anchor relative, your anchor class would look something like this:

```
a.preview:hover {
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:40;
}
```

To position this new image relative to its parent anchor we give it some styling, in this case making it show up in the left top of the anchor:

```
a.preview img.hover {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display: none; /* so it doesn't show by default */
}
```

And to make it show up when hovering the link we can make another hover class for `a.preview`:

```
a.preview:hover img.hover {
    display: block;
}
```

(I added this answer in hope searchers will get an alternative usable answer)